# DatePicker and TimePicker code not working together ("protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)" is already defined)

Tags: android, datepicker, timepicker

I have created an app, in which I have a DatePicker and a TimePicker. First I made the Datepicker and I displayed it when I selected the Date textview, this worked perfectly fine. Then I wanted to do the same for the Time EditText but instead of displaying a DatePicker it is supposed to display a TimePicker when selected.

After I implemented the code for the TimePicker: The error is that the "protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)" is already defined and I cannot use this method twice.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that  you have only one DialogFragment for both date and time pickers... this will create a conflict as you have already implemented the onCreateDialog.

what I usually do is I create another class for each component that i would like to have a different implementation of onCreateDialog.

```
public class DatePickerDialog  extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          ...
        }



 public class TimePickerDialog  extends DialogFragment implements 
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{
                @Override
                public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  ...
                }
```

then I would call it in the activity like ...

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog();
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
dialog.show(fm, "Date Picker");
```

this way you could also add custom callbacks or listeners for each picker and use them multiple times in one activity.